# How can I get rid of my nostril hairs?

Tags: personal-care, hair

I've hit "2nd puberty" and now get hair growing inside my nostrils. I have little scissors to get at them but it's uncomfortable and never seems to work well.

If getting rid of them completely isn't an option I'd accept an answer on what is the most efficient and effective way to trim them down.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't turning out to be a life hack. It's just a how-to for general grooming needs. I'm going to close this as *not a lifehack.*

Comment: Tweezers work wonders.

Comment: Nostril hair trimmer.It is like a regular trimmer but tapered a one end.

Answer (score 1):

Your once-in-awhile option would be to get a Nasal Waxing treatment, this would leave your nasal canals all fresh and hairless.

What I think you're after is a more practical solution, and for that I would suggest a Nasal Trimmer

Heres a link to a good one : http://www.boots.com/en/Wahl-5546-517Y-Spotlight-Ear-Nose-Brow-Personal-Trimmer_1274642/

Worth the investment.